# What does "Forrest Gump" mean in Samantha words?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-mexican

In The Mexican (2001), Samantha says to Jerry after reuniting with him:

> We are going to get your passport in order and you are gonna give the
>   gun to Margolese. Nayman is f*cking Margolese. That has nothing to do
>   with us. By the grace of God, I don't know what, you have managed to
>   **Forrest Gump** your way through this. And just, if we run now. we're
>   gonna be running the rest of our lives.

I know Forrest Gump is a movie name starring Tom Hanks. But how does this movie 
title fit here in her statement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You know "Forrest Gump" is the name of a movie starring Tom Hanks, but I'm guessing you haven't actually seen that movie.  In that movie, the titular character, Forrest Gump, is a slow-witted man who recounts his life story which - for the most part - involves him stumbling from one situation to another with hapless optimism and little, if any, clue what impact his actions are having on the people around him.  Being a feel-good movie, it mostly works out for the best, but that's beside the point for this question.

Samantha is suggesting that Jerry, much like Forrest Gump, has come a long way without really knowing what he's doing, or what the consequences of his actions will be.  She's also probably trying to insult him, by suggesting that she thinks he's intellectually disabled.

Comment: But does the following sentence, "And just, **if we run now. we're gonna be running the rest of our lives**.", not suggest that "Forrest Gumping" is synonymous with "running without considering any other option"? I.e. she isn't specifically saying that he's blindly stumbling through life, but rather that he has an innate tendency to run away without questioning it.

Comment: @Flater Also a very valid interpretation.  I don't think the two are mutually exclusive though.

Comment: @Flater Samantha's "Forrest Gump" reference there is specifically to what he has been doing so far ("you have managed to Forrest Gump your way through this"). While she goes on to suggest that Jerry is at the point where he might be now considering running ("*if* we run now"), which is another but different thing Forrest Gump does, she's not referring to his possible future running when she says it, and indeed she's suggesting that they shouldn't run. I think the answer is correct as it stands.